# Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string' in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to count the no of rows returned from linq to sql and passing its value from controlller to view through viewBag but its is giving an error Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'

View

```
@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.totalSpaces)
```

Controller

```
List<RentOutSpace> parkingSpaces = searchModel.searchSpace(address);
int count = parkingSpaces.Count();
string countSpace = count.ToString();
ViewBag.totalSpaces = countSpace;
```

Comment: What is not clear? `Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string`

Comment: I want to assign value of viewBag to a label but how i can i achieve this cx cannot convert 'int' to string'

Comment: Everything here looks correct. Are you able to get a stack trace or use a debugger to determine the exact line the error is happening on?

Comment: You just missed the @ as the prefex of ViewBag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the @Html.Label

Just use

```
@ViewBag.totalSpaces
```

Or
Html.Label((string)@ViewBag.totalSpaces)

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@Html.Label(ViewBag.totalSpaces)
```

Comment: From what we can see, what's being set into the `ViewBag` is a `string` anyway, and calling `ToString()` on a string doesn't do much. The question is currently unclear.

Comment: as i told that we cannot convert int to string in linq to sql.when i apply toString method it remains still as int when it is passed to viewBag.

Comment: @christos i trid u solution it is giving error Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. Everything is set into the ViewBag is a string and for that reason the .ToString() is not needed.

Comment: @Wasfa what you are saying is not possible